# Javascript does'nt switch div visibility

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, visibility

I'm working on a script that would allow me to change which div is visible, but right now it does'nt work and i can't figure out why.

Could someone help me to find a solution ?

html

```
<div id="send2" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute">
    <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mascarene_martin" name="send a request" width="960px" height="577px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div id="send3" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute">
    <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acacia_cultriformis" name="send a request" width="960px" height="577px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div id="send4" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute">
    <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Halmyros" width="960px" height="577px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div id="send5" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute">
    <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Detroit_Arena" width="960px" height="577px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div id="nav_buttons">
    <button id="previous" onclick="SwitchPageBackward()" style="margin-top: 614px">Previous
    </button>        
    <button id="next" onclick="SwitchPageForward()" style="margin-top: 614px">Next
    </button>
</div>
```

script

```
Page1.style.visibility="visible"
Page2.style.visibility="hidden"
Page3.style.visibility="hidden"
Page4.style.visibility="hidden"
Page5.style.visibility="hidden"

function SwitchPageForward() {
var Page1 = document.getElementById("send1");
var Page2 = document.getElementById("send2");
var Page3 = document.getElementById("send3");
var Page4 = document.getElementById("send4");
var Page5 = document.getElementById("send5");

if (Page4.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page4.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page5.style.visibility="visible";
}

if (Page3.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page3.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page4.style.visibility="visible";
} 

if (Page2.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page2.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page3.style.visibility="visible";
}
else if (Page2.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page2.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page3.style.visibility="visible";
}
if  (Page1.style.visibility == "visible"){
 Page1.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page2.style.visibility="visible";
}
 else if (Page1.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page1.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page3.style.visibility="visible";
}
 else if (Page1.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page1.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page4.style.visibility="visible";
}
}
function SwitchPageBackward() {
var Page1 = document.getElementById("send1");
var Page2 = document.getElementById("send2");
var Page3 = document.getElementById("send3");
var Page4 = document.getElementById("send4");
var Page5 = document.getElementById("send5");

if (Page2.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page2.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page1.style.visibility="visible";
}

if (Page3.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page3.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page2.style.visibility="visible";
}
 else if (Page3.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page3.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page1.style.visibility="visible";
}

if (Page4.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page4.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page3.style.visibility="visible";
}
 else if (Page4.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page4.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page2.style.visibility="visible";
}
else if (Page5.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page4.style.visibility="hidden";
 Page1.style.visibility="visible";
}

if (Page5.style.visibility == "visible") {
 Page4.style.visibility="hidden";
}

}
```

when i click on next, I would like page_x to become invisible and page_x+1 to become visible.(previous button would reverse this process).

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6Lpq8p5x/

Comment: (Argh, failed to notice the scroll bar...)

Comment: you have one major error in your code: You define `var Page1` outside of a function. This makes it a global variable. And then you define `Page1` inside each function as a global variable too, overwriting the previous statement. why?

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm still new to javascript. So basically i need to define my variables in my function ? I'm going try it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend if you code Javascript like this you will be writing it in Megabytes, please refer JSFiddle Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/sameersemna/p5yzLL18/

```
function hideAllPages(){
    for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
        document.getElementById("send"+i).style.visibility="hidden"; 
    }
}


function switchPageForward() {
    if(current_page<5){
        current_page++; 
        hideAllPages();        document.getElementById("send"+current_page).style.visibility="visible";
    }
}
function switchPageBackward() {
    if(current_page>1){
        current_page--;
        hideAllPages();
document.getElementById("send"+current_page).style.visibility="visible";
    }
}



hideAllPages();
var current_page = 0;
switchPageForward();
```

Comment: Wow, your code is actually way simpler than mine and it works.  I'll study how you wrote your code and format my next codes the same way. Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to the world of Javascripting my friend. Do yourself a favor learn jQuery. Do me a favor upvote :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, please don't hard-code each entry like you have. Use an index to specify which div should be visible, and just show that one, and hide the others, in the callback.

(I can provide more detail if needed.)

Something like this should work (but doesn't, for some reason. ;-) ):

```
var index = 1;
function SwitchPageForward() {
    alert('foo');
    document.getElementById("send"+index).style.visibility = "hidden";
    index++;
    document.getElementById("send"+index).style.visibility = "visible";
}
function SwitchPageBackward() {
    document.getElementById("send"+index).style.visibility = "hidden";
    index--;
    document.getElementById("send"+index).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: I thought it qualified as an answer, because of the "Use an index to specify which div should be visible" part.

Comment: Thanks for telling me, i'll try to make it more simple/easier to understand.

Comment: Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I'm not sure of how i should make an index, could you tell me how ?